# My data isn't retained when the UITableViewCell is reuse - SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm having some difficulties when i scroll down my TableView , the datas from my cells are disappearing . How can I retain them to be more specific in my DataSource?

Mention that my cell is having a collection view inside it , and the items from it are shown bad.

```
class PromoTowerCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var multiplierNumberLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var iconPromo: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var namePromoLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var priceCutLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var priceActualLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var infoPopUp: MyButton!

    // MARK: - Setters
var kid : PromoPackageKid? {
    didSet {
        self.namePromoLabel.text = kid?.name
        self.multiplierNumberLabel.text = kid?.power
        self.priceActualLabel.text = String(describing: kid!.prices[Constants.CARD_PAYMENT]!) + " €"
        self.infoPopUp.promoText = kid?.texts
        if kid?.prices[Constants.CARD_PAYMENT] != kid?.commonPrices[Constants.CARD_PAYMENT] {
            let stringPrice = String(describing:kid!.commonPrices[Constants.CARD_PAYMENT]!) + " €"
            let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringPrice)
            attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
            self.priceCutLabel.attributedText = attributeString
        } else {
            self.priceCutLabel.isHidden = true
        }

    }
}
```

That would be my collectionViewItem with the data that I m populating it.

```
class PromoTowerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var package : PromoPackage? {
    didSet {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

        @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: PromoTowerCollectionView!

    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PromoTowerCollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PromoTowerCollectionViewCell")

        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }
}

// MARK: DataSource
extension PromoTowerTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return package?.kids.count ?? 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PromoTowerCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PromoTowerCollectionViewCell
        cell.kid = package?.kids[indexPath.row]
        cell.iconPromo.image = UIImage(named: iconImages[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}

        //MARK: Delegate

    extension PromoTowerTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PromoTowerCollectionViewCell {
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.defaultColor().cgColor
            cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0.5, height: 0.5)
        }
    }
```

As for my MainTableView =>

```
     // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource + Delegate
    func expandableCell(forSection section: Int, inTableView tableView: ExpyTableView) -> UITableViewCell {
        let currentPackage = self.packages[section]
        if section < self.packages.count {
        if currentPackage.type == "bundle"{
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PromoTowerCell") as! PromoTowerTableViewCell
                cell.package = currentPackage
                return cell
            }
```

Comment: You should set the values in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `Datasource and Delegate` should be in the `ViewController` holding your `collectionView`, the cell should only contain your `UIViews`, You are setting the cell content in the cell it self that `tableView` or `collectionView` will reload the cell and you'll lose your data, while you should set your values in the `cellForRowAtIndexpath`, the approach you are following is really weird.

```
arrayOne = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
arrayTwo = ["Item A", "Item B", "Item C"]

// MARK: Delegate & DataSource
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOne.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PromoTowerCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PromoTowerCollectionViewCell

       cell.iconPromo.text = arrayOne[indexPath.row]
       cell.namePromoLabel.text = arrayTwo[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response. BTW where label is? Use of unresolved identifier 'label'. Please explain with what do you want me to replace label?

Comment: Label is the array of items you want to display for each cell, for each priceCutLabel will have an array of those items, priceCutArray = [23,44,66] so your cell.priceCutLabel.text = priceCutArray[indexPath.row]

Comment: well, that didn't help. The thing is all the data's come from cell.kid = package?.kids[indexPath.row] where kid is set in the collectionViewCell

Comment: I need somehow a model to retain my data when I reuse the cell after scrolling . Also it messes my data when i select another tableViewCell

Comment: Your Cell data needs to be in the `tableView delegate`, to be able to display the data separately inside each cell, you need to have the cell as a placeholder for items, and then update the cell labels using the `cellForRowatindexPath`, so in the `tableView` ViewController define some array's from your labels and set the cell, you can not update the data inside the cell it self, because the cell for row method will keep on updating the cells and your data will be lost. remove `cell.kid = package?.kids[indexPath.row]`

Comment: or `collectionView` delegate, I updated my answer, check it out.